# Problems accessing pre-defined array of floats in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, floating-point

I'm trying to make use of precalculated values by outputting them to a header file and then compiling them for use.

The precalculated values are cube co ordinates mapped onto a sphere and the data structure takes the form of:

```
typedef float heightMapCubeFace[5][5][3];
```

I am defining each face seperately like so:

```
    heightMapCubeFace face1 = {{{ -2.88675, -2.88675, -2.88675 }, { -3.38502, -3.38502, -1.44338 }, { -3.53553, -3.53553, 0 }, { -3.38502, -3.38502, 1.44338 }, { -2.88675, -2.88675, 2.88675}}, 
{{ -1.44338, -3.38502, -3.38502 }, { -1.69251, -4.38986, -1.69251 }, { -1.76777, -4.67707, 0 }, { -1.69251, -4.38986, 1.69251 }, { -1.44338, -3.38502, 3.38502}}, 
{{ 0, -3.53553, -3.53553 }, { 0, -4.67707, -1.76777 }, { 0, -5, 0 }, { 0, -4.67707, 1.76777 }, { 0, -3.53553, 3.53553}}, 
{{ 1.44338, -3.38502, -3.38502 }, { 1.69251, -4.38986, -1.69251 }, { 1.76777, -4.67707, 0 }, { 1.69251, -4.38986, 1.69251 }, { 1.44338, -3.38502, 3.38502}}, 
{{ 2.88675, -2.88675, -2.88675 }, { 3.38502, -3.38502, -1.44338 }, { 3.53553, -3.53553, 0 }, { 3.38502, -3.38502, 1.44338 }, { 2.88675, -2.88675, 2.88675}} 
};
```

and finally:

```
heightMapCubeFace * heightMapSaved[6] = {&face1, &face2, &face3, &face4, &face5, &face6};
```

Eventually the data structue will be bigger I hav ejust set it to 5x5 to make things easier at first.

The problem I am having is when I want to get the values back, something weird is happening and as a result access violations are occuring.

As shown in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVT4s.png)

As you can see the assigned value does not match that of the data structure.  Instead the value for index `[0][0][0][1]` is given the value of index `[0][0][1][0]`.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP29K.png)

I picked up on this because an unhaddled exception is thrown at a later stage (access violation), I think it is because of this index problem but can't be certain.

I don't understand what is going on, am I dereferencing the pointer wrong?

Any help would be much appriciated, thanks.

Here is the code for that section:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {    
        for(int j = 0; j < heightMapRes; j++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < heightMapRes; k++)
            {
                float xCoord =  *(heightMapSaved[i][j][k][0]);
                float yCoord =  *(heightMapSaved[i][j][k][1]);
                float zCoord =  *(heightMapSaved[i][j][k][2]);

                float newValue = myModule.GetValue( xCoord, yCoord, zCoord);

                heightMap.SetValue( j, k, newValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of screenshots, it is better to post small code fragment that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Without seeing the code it is difficult (the images are non-conclusive as for the code). You may have to review again the code to see if at any point you've mixed two indexes... happens a lot with multi-dimensional structures.

Comment: OK have reposted the code for that loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

layout is `(heightMapSaved[6])[5][5][3]` not `(heightMapSaved[5][5][3][6])`